# Extract some part from filename as variable

Tags: bash, double-quotes

I have read some threads about extracting some parts from filename, but still cannot solve my problem.
There are some files named `aa - bb.txt`, `cc - dd.txt`, `ee - ff.txt`, etc.
And the last line in every file is like this:

```
somewordbbaa
```

for `aa - bb.txt` and for `cc - dd.txt` is:

```
somewordddcc
```

Then in `ee - ff.txt` is:

```
somewordffee
```

I want to write a shell script to delete the bbaa, ddcc, ffee in last line of the respective file. I have tried following:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.txt
do
  artist=`echo $file | awk -F'[ .]' '{print $1}'`
  name=`echo $file | awk -F'[ .]' '{print $3}'`
  echo $artist >> artist
  echo $name >> name
  sed -i "s/$name$artist//" $file
done
```

And after I ran it,it threw this

```
sed: can't read aa: No such file or directory
sed: can't read -: No such file or directory
sed: can't read bb.txt: No such file or directory
sed: can't read cc: No such file or directory
sed: can't read -: No such file or directory
sed: can't read dd.txt: No such file or directory
sed: can't read ee: No such file or directory
sed: can't read -: No such file or directory
sed: can't read ff.txt: No such file or directory
```

I also tried this

```
#!/bin/bash
ls *.txt | sed 's/\.txt//' > full_name
cut -f1 -d" " full_name > artist
cut -f3 -d" " full_name > name

for file in `ls -1 *.txt`, item1 in artist, item2 in name #Is this right?
do
  tail -n -1 $file | sed 's/$item2$item1//' > $file.last #just the last line
done
```

It just showed this and had no reaction until pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

```
tail: cannot open `aa' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I think bash puts the blank of the filename as the separator, reads the `$file` as `aa`, `-`, `bb.txt`.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your files have a space in the name, try your original script but change this line:

`sed -i "s/$name$artist//" $file`

to this:

`sed -i "s/$name$artist//" "$file"`